# Term for describing defensive reflexes when no harmful action is being initiated

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

A little background:

I wanted to button up my sleeve, so naturally I moved both of my arms up to my chest level and that is when my friend thought I wanted to hit him so he took a defensive reflex.

The thing is this scenario happened multiple times when he would just take a defensive reflex in such situations.

I said "stop being paranoid", But a friend of me argued that paranoia is not the word to describe this situation. I kind of agree, paranoia is an overstatement. But what other alternatives do I have ?

Comment: 'Defensive' works. Welcome to EL&U.

Comment: Have you tried to hit him when he does this? Is his goal to defend, or to counter attack?

Answer (score 1):

If you’re looking for a replacement for *paranoid* in “Stop being so paranoid”, consider *jumpy*. It retains the suggestion of a reflex action and self-preservation, but stops short of outright paranoia.

> **jumpy** *adjective, informal*
>   1 (of a person) anxious and uneasy.
>   ‘he was tired and jumpy’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/jumpy)

Comment: My thought, too. Also, "reactionary" could work if it were something more than a momentary movement.

Answer (score 0):

**withdrawal reaction**  [TFD](https://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/defense+reflex)

**withdrawal reaction**
Segen's Medical Dictionary. © 2012 Farlex, Inc. 
*a type of defense reflex*
Retraction or tension in response to an action or threatened action.